# Race condition leading to Highcharts error #13

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I have some tabs which are generated dynamically. Clicking on any of this tabs loads multiple charts(three or four) like a pie, column or a linechart simultaneously. I append this charts into dynamically generated html divs. All works good if i had to click a tab and wait for all the charts to be loaded. Problem happens when i keep on clicking tabs one after the other and not wait till all the charts are loaded. i get a javascript error inside highcharts.js file which logs Highcharts error #13. As far as i know i am doing proper document ready checks and then loading my charts into the divs. What seems to be the problem ? Is there a race condition happening or due to my code running asynchronously leading to problems? Here is the code:

```
//Function called on tablick:
function GetPod(podObj) {

        savedPortletsObj = [];
        var objtab = new Array();
        var htmlMarkup = '';
        $('#podHolder').empty();

        for (v = 0, pCount = podObj.length; v < pCount; v++) {
            htmlMarkup = "";
            // htmlMarkup = htmlMarkup + " <div  class='table-cell'>";
            htmlMarkup = htmlMarkup + " <article class='db-box bigFont' id='" + podObj[v].id + "_art' style='height: 100%;'>";
            htmlMarkup = htmlMarkup + " <div class='box-head' ><span> <strong>" + podObj[v].title.toString() + "</strong></span></div>";
            htmlMarkup = htmlMarkup + " <div class='dashboard-container'>";
            htmlMarkup = htmlMarkup + " <div class='tableContentDiv height250 fadeInBox' id='" + podObj[v].id + "'> "; // Charts are appended into this div
            htmlMarkup = htmlMarkup + " </div>";
            htmlMarkup = htmlMarkup + " </div>";
            htmlMarkup = htmlMarkup + " </article>";
            // htmlMarkup = htmlMarkup + " </div>";
            $(htmlMarkup).appendTo($('#podHolder')); // Finally appending the chart div to the parent div
            buildChart(podObj[v]);
            savedPortletsObj[v] = podObj[v];
        }
```

// Then i call buildChart

```
function buildChart(podObj) {
        switch (podObj.PodAttributes.type) {
            case "ColumnChart":
                // chartTypes[podObj.id] = podObj.PodAttributes.type;
              //  requirejs(["HTML5SpendDashboard/includes/js/views/column.chart.js"], function () {
                    var objChart = ColumnChart.getInstance();
                    onSuccessLoadChart(podObj, objChart);
              //  });
                break;
            case "dataGrid":
                //  chartTypes[podObj.id] = podObj.PodAttributes.type;
               // requirejs(["HTML5SpendDashboard/includes/js/views/grid.js"], function () {
                    var objChart = DataGrid.getInstance();
                    onSuccessLoadChart(podObj, objChart);
               // });

                break;
            case "lineChart":
               // //  chartTypes[podObj.id] = podObj.PodAttributes.type;
                //requirejs(["HTML5SpendDashboard/includes/js/views/line.chart.js"], function () {
                    var objChart = LineChart.getInstance();
                    onSuccessLoadChart(podObj, objChart);
               // });
                break;
            case "pieChart":
                //  chartTypes[podObj.id] = podObj.PodAttributes.type;
               // requirejs(["HTML5SpendDashboard/includes/js/views/pie.chart.js"], function () {
                    var objChart = PieChart.getInstance();
                    onSuccessLoadChart(podObj, objChart);
              //  });
                break;
        }
    }
    function onSuccessLoadChart(podObj, objChart) {

        objChart.BaseViewRef.Variables.ViewProperties = podObj;
        objChart.Build();

    }
```

// FInally Build is called after the instance was created for it , For eg: Column chart will be (Have created a separate js files for each chart)

```
var ColumnChart = (function () {
var instantiated;
var chart;
function init() {
    return {
        "ResultMethodName": "onResultHttpService",
        "Message": "ColumnChartdemo",
        "Build": function () {
            var objServiceLayer = $SL.getInstance();
            var param = {};
            param["QueryID"] = this.BaseViewRef.Variables.ViewProperties.InputParams;
            objServiceLayer.executeMethod("GetPodFilterData", param, "onResultHttpService", this, this.BaseViewRef.Variables.ViewProperties);

        },
        "BaseViewRef": $BV.getInstance(),
        "onResultHttpService": function (result, properties) {
            var json_str = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(result);
            var data = [];
            var cat = [];
            var categoryField = properties.PodAttributes.categoryField;
            var valueField = properties.PodAttributes.valueField;
            for (var i in json_str) {
                var serie = new Array(json_str[i][categoryField], json_str[i][valueField]);
                var tmpCat = new Array(json_str[i][categoryField]);
                data.push(serie);
                cat.push(tmpCat);
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: properties.id,
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: cat
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        labels: {
                            formatter: function () {
                                return this.value / properties.PodAttributes.divideBy
                            + properties.PodAttributes.dataTipUnitLabel.split('*')[1].toUpperCase();
                            }
                        },
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        align: 'left',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: 100,
                        y: 70,
                        floating: true,
                        shadow: true
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '' +
                        this.x + ':' + '</br>' + properties.PodAttributes.dataTipUnitLabel.split('*')[0] +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / properties.PodAttributes.divideBy, properties.PodAttributes.dPoint) +
                        properties.PodAttributes.dataTipUnitLabel.split('*')[1].toUpperCase();
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            allowPointSelect: true,
                            point: {
                                events: { click: function () {
                                    //                                    alert(this.category + ' : ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y / properties.PodAttributes.divideBy, properties.PodAttributes.dPoint) +
                                    //                            properties.PodAttributes.dataTipUnitLabel.split('*')[1].toUpperCase());
                                    podsToRefresh = html5SpendDashboard.getInstance().getSavedPodObj();
                                    var objBuildChart = html5SpendDashboard.getInstance();
                                    for (var p = 0, pLen = podsToRefresh.length; p < pLen; p++) {
                                        objBuildChart.buildChart(podsToRefresh[p]);
                                    }
                                }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        column: {
                            pointPadding: 0.2,
                            borderWidth: 0
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        showInLegend: false,
                        data: data
                    }]
                });
            });         
        }

    };
};

return {
    getInstance: function () {
        return instantiated = init();
    }
};
```

})();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with updating charts in real time.  I was able to avoid this scenario by first checking to make sure that the container exists before I would update the chart.

In your case you could do something like this to make sure that the container exists:

```
if($("#" + properties.id).length == 1) {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                 //code
            });
}
```

Comment: absolutely..the asynchronous calls were the problem..as soon as the first request was sent, the html container was drawn but as the other tabs were being clicked new request were sent and before charts for the previous request were created and appended my new request was destroying the previous containers. RESOLVED it by adding the above code just before were i was creating the chart:     if ($("#" + properties.id).length == 0) {
                    return false;
                }