# Highcharts error #13, Turbolinks Rendering Partials Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts, turbolinks

Using Highcharts 3.0.7 & Turbolinks, I'm running into a sporadic problem while rendering my charts.

I've got a couple of dozen pages of charts and, *on some pages only*, I'm getting the missing div (error 13) message.

First, I had assumed this is because the pages are loaded asynchronously, as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176201/race-condition-leading-to-highcharts-error-13). I think I'm wrong.

Using the following JS (within an erb partial):

```
<script>
var ready;
ready = function() {
  if($("#header_chart").length == 1) {
    console.log('Visible')
    lineChart("header_chart", '<%= raw @chart_series %>', "<%= @range %>", "Title");
  }
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
</script>
```

I thought dropping the if statement would help, at least temporarily. However, I can see that turbolinks seems to be rendering the partial (or least the script) multiple times. Even when I click another link that should not load it..

I've tried everything I can think of:

- If I refresh the page, I see visible once in the console. If I click the link, I see it logged a couple of times.
- If I click the link from another page, it's not appearing - the div is not on the page although it clearly is.
- Tried removing the page:load turbolinks part without success. The only similarity is that I have two different pages with charts rendering into a div with the same name.
- Tried changing the div name, no success.
- Moving the js into a separate file and or out of the partial.

Can someone help me solve this please.
I've even changed the name of the function without success.

Comment: Highcharts error means that you have no renderTo defined, in other words, div where chart should be printed, not exists. Chart should be initialized after loading DOM element, so have you live demo of your chart?

Comment: The problem seems to be that turbolinks is rendering the page contents but not necessarily updating the page structure. It leaves stuff behind and doesn't render new divs before rendering the partials. As the pages are almost identical, it works most times until I introduce a new div to render the chart to. The only work around I've found is to test if the div exists or not.. Seems ridiculous though..

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem, what to do?

Comment: @Michael, I'm not sure if it's related but turolinks have some problems with the `ready` event. Check my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649910/unable-to-unbind-event-listener-trouble-with-turbolinks-caching/39650042#39650042, let me know if it works.

Comment: @Michael, did you manage to check my answer there?

Comment: Sorry I didn't manage to check, my team made another solution to this problem!