# Unable to unbind event listener - trouble with turbolinks caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener, turbolinks

I'm binding then unbinding the ready event listener to the document.

```
$(document).bind("ready", readyEventHandler);

function readyEventHandler() {
  // run some code

  $(document).unbind("ready");
}
```

The code produces no errors and will work. However, my javascript is cached and duplicates the code so I'll end up with having this code run more than once if I go back and then forward a page in the browser. When this happens, the ready event listener is not called at all. Am I properly unbinding this event listener? I know the caching issue becomes problematic(it's own separate issue) but I just want to bind the ready event listener, have it run code, then unbind it.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to re-bind `ready`. It only happens once, when the page is first loaded.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish by unbinding and re-binding the ready event?

Comment: @Barmar, this is not correct. The `ready` event will fire once the document is ready (which means if you bind the `ready` event after the document is ready - the callback function will just get called immediately).

Comment: When you go back and forward in history, I think browsers differ in whether they re-run the Javascript that should run when the page is first loaded.

Comment: I've updated my question so it hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: @Barmar, I really don't want this question to be about the caching. Although the caching is a problem, it's one that currently can't be fixed. I'm stuck with some javascript that will load multiple times and I just want the `readyEventHandler` called once. Not twice, not three times, once. `$(document).ready` doesn't do that. `bind("ready")` does. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Barmar jQuery's `ready` event behaves differently from other events. From jQuery's [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) docs: "However, jQuery's .ready() method differs in an important and useful way: If the DOM becomes ready and the browser fires DOMContentLoaded before the code calls .ready( handler ), the function handler will still be executed. In contrast, a DOMContentLoaded event listener added after the event fires is never executed." This means `ready` handlers will still fire even when attached well after the document has finished loading.

Comment: @Ouroborus It also says: "There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0.". Since `.bind()` just calls `.on()`, this also applies to `.bind()`. So he should use `$(document).ready()` rather than `.bind()`.

Comment: @Barmar That was in response to your first comment where you incorrectly assert that `ready` "only happens once, when the page is first loaded."

Comment: @Ouroborus I mistakenly thought it behaved differently when you called `.bind()` rather than `.ready()`.

Comment: @jason328 I don't think you can divorce it from the caching. If returning to the page reloads it, any state you created will be reset -- it will be just as if you'd visited the page the first time, and it will re-run the `ready` handler even if you unbound it. If it just resumes the page without reloading, nothing will be re-run, so you don't need to unbind.

Comment: @Barmar, I wish I could further explain. Turbolinks is really frustrating to explain. I'm going to write another question reworded in a way that makes better sense. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not so sure it will help, but here are my 2 cents - instead of trying to unbind the `readyEventHandler` - make sure that if you run the function once it will not run twice:

```
var readyHandlerRun = false;

$(document).bind("ready", readyEventHandler);

function readyEventHandler() {
    if (readyHandlerRun) {
        return;
    }
    readyHandlerRun = true;
    // Rest of your code...
}
```

Another options that popped just now:

```js
$(document).bind("ready", readyEventHandler);
function readyEventHandler() {
  readyEventHandler = function() { }  
  
  console.log('ready');
  // Rest of your code...
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE** (by @jason328)

After talking with Dekel he provided me the appropriate answer.

```
$(document).bind("ready", function() {
    readyEventHandler();
    readyEventHandler = function() { }
});
```

Elegant and works like a charm!

Comment: That is a fantastic solution. It was the one I actually proposed. But at this time we are trying to see if there are other solutions to this, mainly through unbinding the event listener. This solution can become problematic with our code. That said if no one else responds with a valid answer using unbind I'll give you credit.

Comment: My situation is unique and I think this solution works well for everyone else. Just not me :/

Comment: I'm trying to understand how/where exactly your code will run the `readyEventHandler` twice...

Comment: Turbolinks caching. It's hell sometimes. To elaborate, Turbolinks stores multiple copies of of Javascript each time I hit the page (let's call it the home page). Every time I hit back and then forward in the browser, Turbolinks caches the JS code for the home page. So if my JS code has `$(document).ready` and there are multiple caches of that code stored by Turbolinks, AND I hit the home page, then multiple document ready eventHandlers will be called. I'm trying to solve this by using `bind`.

Comment: Then your problem is that even if you `unbind` this event - it will get bind again by turbolinks once the JS code will be taken from the cache, and the callback will get called.. The only solution is to prevent the function from running if it run already, and you really must have a global variable to tell you that.

Comment: It sounds like I can, but it won't. Sorry for the confusion about all of this. I was hoping to ask a question without getting into the caching details, but the two are so linked together.

Comment: Seems like. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: @jason328, check the update on my answer, might serve you better :)

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you further explain your alternate answer?

Comment: If you override the `readyEventHandler` to make it an "empty" function - even if that function will get called again (without creating the function) the code that will run will be just the empty function.

Comment: Oh wait. That's interesting. Ok, let's see how it goes. Testing now.

Comment: The big question here is if turbolinks override the functions (and the callback) on only call the `ready` event or whatever...

Comment: sorry. It did not work. It will work when I first refresh the page but after pressing back and then forward in the browser, I got nothing. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123993/discussion-between-dekel-and-jason328).

Answer (score 1):

if you just would like to use an eventhamdler only once, you could use `one` instead of `bind`

```
$(document).one("ready", function() {
   // code to run on document ready just for once
});
```