# Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13 how to solve this error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, highcharts

I am new to charts 
I have index.jsp page.In that page contains CSS ,JAVASCRIPT also.I want to display BAR CHART in that jsp page..

I am getting this type of error::**Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13**

**Thanks in Advance**

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Line Charts</title>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
container {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }]

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color:red" align="center">WELCOME TO LINE CHARTS</h1>


<div id="container" name="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Race condition leading to Highcharts error #13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176201/race-condition-leading-to-highcharts-error-13)

Answer (score 5):

This means you need to move the `<div id="container" name="container"></div>`  before you call the `Highcharts.chart`

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

      title: {
          text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
      },

      subtitle: {
          text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
      },

      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Number of Employees'
          }
      },
      legend: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'middle'
      },

      plotOptions: {
          series: {
              pointStart: 2010
          }
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Installation',
          data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
      }, {
          name: 'Manufacturing',
          data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
      }, {
          name: 'Sales & Distribution',
          data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
      }, {
          name: 'Project Development',
          data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
      }, {
          name: 'Other',
          data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
      }]

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<h1 style="color:red" align="center">WELCOME TO LINE CHARTS</h1>


<div id="container" name="container"></div>
```