# Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13 - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using high charts in Angular. I'm using track js to track errors. In that, I'm getting this error more count. But I couldn't find the cause and i couldn't reproduce this issue.

```
 "Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13"
```

I hope you guys can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13 how to solve this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275851/highcharts-error-13-www-highcharts-com-errors-13-how-to-solve-this-error)